# JsonArray get all names - php

Tags: php, json

i want to call all names from one [ ] , Array not work from foreach php ? or i can't what i want to do , i used foreach ("id","NOT LIKE",$id) , but when take echo form out of foreach , only show one names , 
Here is my php code :

```
if ($getusers !== FALSE) {

    $json["error_two"] = FALSE;

    foreach($db->get("users",array('id', 'NOT LIKE', $id))->results() as $u){

        $user = new user( $u->id );

        $json = array(
            'error_two' => FALSE,
            'getusers' => $getusers,
            'call_two' => [
                array(
                    'user_id' => $user->data()->id,
                    'fname' => $user->data()->fname,
                    'lname' => $user->data()->lname,
                    'username' => $user->data()->username,
                    'gender' => $user->data()->gender,
                ),
            ]
        );   
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
}
```

Out :

```
{"error_two":false,"getusers":true,"call_two":[{"user_id":"1","fname":"Ned","lname":"Stark","username":"","gender":"Male"}]}{"error_two":false,"getusers":true,"call_two":[{"user_id":"3","fname":"Danyal","lname":"Join","username":"","gender":"Male"}]}{"error_two":false,"getusers":true,"call_two":[{"user_id":"4","fname":"dnianas","lname":".co","username":"","gender":"Male"}]}{"error_two":false,"getusers":true,"call_two":[{"user_id":"5","fname":"Mr.","lname":"Robot","username":"","gender":"Male"}]}
```

exactly i want :

```
{
"call_two" : [
        {
            "user_id" = "1",
            "fname" = "Ned",
            "lname" = "Stark",
            "username" = "",
            "gender" = "Male"
        },
        {
            "user_id" = "2",
            "fname" = "Jon",
            "lname" = "Snow",
            "username" = "",
            "gender" = "Male"
        },
        {
            "user_id" = "3",
            "fname" = "Danyal",
            "lname" = "Join",
            "username" = "",
            "gender" = "Male"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... i used foreach ("id","NOT LIKE",$id) , but when take echo form out of foreach , only show one names ...

That's because you are over-writing `$json` in each iteration of `foreach` loop. Also, that's not a invalid JSON string you mentioned *there*. To achieve a valid (and somewhat expected JSON string), your `if` block should be like this:

```
if ($getusers !== false) {
    $json = array('error_two' => false, 'getusers' => $getusers);
    foreach($db->get("users",array('id', 'NOT LIKE', $id))->results() as $u){
        $user = new user( $u->id );
        $json['call_two'][] = array(
                                'user_id' => $user->data()->id,
                                'fname' => $user->data()->fname,
                                'lname' => $user->data()->lname,
                                'username' => $user->data()->username,
                                'gender' => $user->data()->gender,
                            );
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `'call_two'` instead of adding occurances to that array

```
if ($getusers !== FALSE) {

    $json = array();
    $json["error_two"] = FALSE;
    $json['getusers'] = $getusers;

    foreach($db->get("users",array('id', 'NOT LIKE', $id))->results() as $u){
        $user = new user( $u->id );

        $call_two[] = array(
                            'user_id' => $user->data()->id,
                            'fname' => $user->data()->fname,
                            'lname' => $user->data()->lname,
                            'username' => $user->data()->username,
                            'gender' => $user->data()->gender,
                            );
        );   
    }
    $json['call_two'] = $call_two;

}
echo json_encode($json);
```